# How to stop Pandas from removing enclosing characters from a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I had to trim a very large csv file and I decided to use pandas for it. The file is a CSV and every value in the CSV is enclosed by double quotes.
So the file looked like

```
"Col1", "Col2", "Col3"
"foo", "fii", "fuu"
```

However, upon using `df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='Latin1', low_memory=False)`
all of the double quotes get removed, and after trimming the file and exporting it with `df.to_csv` to a new csv, the new csv has

```
col1, col2, col3
foo, fii, fuu
```

With no enclosing characters.
I definitely need those double quotes, is there a way to preserve them or to add them again?

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `quotechar` parameter? It defaults to `"` and reads it as quoting instead of an actual value.

Comment: No luck, nothing is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL

```
import csv
df.to_csv('out.csv',header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can read csv with `quotechar` option set to something else:

```
from io import StringIO

s = '''"Col1", "Col2", "Col3"
"foo", "fii", "fuu"'''

pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), quotechar="'")
```

Output:

```
  "Col1"  "Col2"  "Col3"
0  "foo"   "fii"   "fuu"
```